# NodeJS CircleCI `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, glibc, circleci

I have NodeJS project that was created in my local machine with `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`. There is `GLIBCXX_3.4.21` installed

Now I am trying to start programm in VM  `CircleCI`, `Ubuntu 14`. Last version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` and I can not update to `3.4.21`

When running in CircleCI I got message :

> module.js:598   return process.dlopen(module,
>   path._makeLong(filename))               ^
>
> Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version
>   `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by
>   /home/circleci/repo/node_modules/scrypt/build/Release/scrypt.node)

My question: 
 how can I update `Ubuntu 14 GLIBCXX_3.4.20` to `GLIBCXX_3.4.21`
OR 
 how can I compile project with `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` if `GLIBCXX_3.4.21` already installed ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to rebuild your project on the target machine.  In general, there is no way around building your project on the *oldest* platform you want to run it on.  The GNU toolchain only offers forward compatibility (run older binaries on newer systems), not backwards compatibility (run newer binaries on older systems).